# Render FBO to same FBO

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, fbo

I am trying to create a ghost-like camera filter. This requires mixing the previous frame to current one. I use one FBO to make the mixing and a second one to simply put the context to the screen.
My implementation works on 4 out of 5 devices I have tried. On the fifth (Samsung galaxy S7) I get some random pixels.

The simpler shader to reproduce the error is the following (the frame counter and cropping is just for debugging). The result is that I get on the center of the screen on line gradually going up.

```
uniform samplerExternalOES camTexture;
uniform sampler2D           fbo;

uniform int                 frame_no;

varying vec2 v_CamTexCoordinate;

void main ()
{
    vec2 uv = v_CamTexCoordinate;

    if(frame_no<10){
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(camTexture, uv);
    }else{
        if(uv.y>0.2 && uv.y<0.8 && uv.x>0.2 && uv.x<0.8)
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(fbo, uv + vec2(0.0, +0.005));
        else
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(camTexture, uv);
    }
}
```

But on the Samsung I get some correct pixels and some random ones as the following sample. Some black and other random pixels going up together with the camera's pixels. Any idea of what might be wrong?

Fault sample
[image: Fault sample]

Correct sample
[image: Correct sample]

Comment: So `fbo` is the currently bound render target?

Comment: I think that you are right - is this undefined? How can I achieve the result that I want?